# accessing variable name in function in R

Tags: r

I've defined the following function:

```
plot_test <- function(data) {
  columns <- names(data)
  for (column in columns) {
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=get(column), y=cluster))
    p <- p + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = .1, width=0.1))
    show(p)
  }
}
```

with input data frame:

```
a <- data.frame(id=c(1,2), cluster=c(3,4))
```

when I run:

```
plot_test(a)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in get(column) : object 'column' not found
```

I am not scoping the column variable in the for loop appropriately. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: surround column in `get` with quotes, e.g. `get("column")`

Comment: @SimonO101: That won't work for this purpose- `get("column")` will be executed to look for the column called `column` in the `data` data frame.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I realised after I typed it. I was assessing what was syntactically wrong first. I +1 your clear and concise explanation though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `aes_string` rather than `get` to pass a column name to ggplot:

```
for (column in columns) {
    p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x=column, y="cluster"))
    p <- p + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = .1, width=0.1))
    show(p)
}
```